# Groovy - list to String with message.properties

Tags: grails

Is there any Groovy method which converts List to String with values substituted from message properties?

```
<g:message code="label.promotion.create.short.${command.daysList.join(",")}"/>
```

Which output data from the `list`, rather I want `code` needs to be taken from message.properties as comma separated

Obviously I can do it through iterating the list, like this

```
<g:each in="${command.daysList}" var="day" status="count">
    <g:message code="label.promotion.create.short.${day}"/>
    <g:if test="${count+1 < command.daysList.size()}">, </g:if>
</g:each>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no shortcut for this.  you can use this in your view:

```
command.dayList.collect{ message(code: "label...${it}") }.join(", ")
```